# Insert JSON in MYSQL

Tags: php, json

How can insert values on input in database mysql by json_encode and foreach, this html code and php code don't work true and done insert value incomplete in database table as: "[" Or "1"

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/LAOJXC

I want they as in database table row:

```
           Column data_1           | Column static
Row1: ["1111111111", "2222222222"] | 12
Row2: ["3333333333", "4444444444"] | 34
Row1: ["5555555555", "6666666666"] | 56
```

```
<input name="data_1[]" value="1111111111">
<input name="data_1[]" value="2222222222">
<input name="static[]" value="12">

<input name="data_1[]" value="3333333333">
<input name="data_1[]" value="4444444444">
<input name="static[]" value="34">

<input name="data_1[]" value="5555555555">
<input name="data_1[]" value="6666666666">
<input name="static[]" value="56">

$data = array();
$data_1 = json_encode($_POST[data_1]);
$static = $_POST[static];
foreach($static as $idx=>$val){
    $data[] = array(
              'data_1' => $data_1[$idx],
              'static' => $static[$idx]
                   )
}

$this->db->insert_batch('MyTable', $data);
```

Comment: what data you are going to store and why JSON

Comment: It seems the problem is in your $this->db object. What's this, some kind of PDO? Does it work if you replace insert_batch to simple insert method (in the loop)? What error throws mysql?

Comment: @Kasheftin I am curious, if you familiar with PHP syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your code only inserts single characters to the database is because you convert the array `$_POST['data_1']` to a string using `json_encode()` and then try to access this string as an array later.

When you access a string with the square brackets notation (in your code: `$data_1[$idx]`), PHP interprets this as a character-access in the string, resulting in only a single character.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose.

Look at this working example:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="data_1[]" value="1111111111">
<input name="data_1[]" value="2222222222">
<input name="static[]" value="12">

<input name="data_1[]" value="3333333333">
<input name="data_1[]" value="4444444444">
<input name="static[]" value="34">

<input name="data_1[]" value="5555555555">
<input name="data_1[]" value="6666666666">
<input name="static[]" value="56">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$data = array();
$data_1 = $_POST['data_1'];
$static = $_POST["static"];
foreach($static as $idx=>$val){
    $data[] = array(
              'data_1' => json_encode(Array($data_1[$idx*2],$data_1[$idx*2+1])),
              'static' => $static[$idx]
                   );
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
?>
```

**DEMO** http://codepad.viper-7.com/ca51ZB

Comment: added some explanation because SO is a place for anyone to learn and understand instead of just getting their problems solved.