# Integration of two fields in a database column

Tags: php, arrays, json

Please see my [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r9FYnb) and answer my question: why date in values html on offset 2 not as date and it is a number?

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/r9FYnb

```
$data = array();
$data_1 = $_POST['data_1'];
$static = $_POST["static"];
foreach($static as $idx=>$val){
    $data[] = array(
          'data_1' => json_encode(Array($data_1[$idx*2],$data_1[$idx]*2+1)),
          'static' => $static[$idx]
           );
}
```

This is output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => ["2011\/8\/02",4023] **//4023 !?**
            [static] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => ["2011\/8\/09",4023] **// 4023!?** 
            [static] => 34
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => ["2011\/8\/16",4023] **// 4023 !?**
            [static] => 56
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do here, but I see an inconsistency between how you manipulate `$idx`

```
'data_1' => json_encode(Array($data_1[$idx*2],$data_1[$idx]*2+1)),
//                              -----^^^^^^^^-------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For the second offset, perhaps you intend to modify `$idx` inside the `[]`

```
'data_1' => json_encode(Array($data_1[$idx*2],$data_1[($idx*2)+1])),
//                               ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Sample output after modifying your demo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => ["2011\/8\/02","2011\/8\/08"]
            [static] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_1] => ["2011\/8\/09","2011\/8\/15"]
            [static] => 34
        )
```

Comment: Yes this is code from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944268/insert-json-in-mysql/7944391#7944391), ive made this simple mistake `$data_1[$idx]*2+1` --> `$data_1[$idx*2+1]`

Comment: @Peter - I question from you about this problem but you don't answer.

Comment: @JimBo Hmmm so why that comment is deleted? :(

Comment: @Peter - It was for several hours ago and i deleted it and ask a new question. In any case, thanks